# Laravel Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ApiController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

For some reason, which is probably my fault, Laravel thinks it should be looking for the class ApiController in path: 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers', so... it doubles, but I have no idea why.

It's a brand new Laravel 6 project, I've created the ApiController with the make:controller artisan command and added a function, like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function base() {
        return 'This is a test function';
    }
}
```

Then I've added a route to the api routes like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'as' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('/base', ['uses' => ApiController::class . '@base'])->name('base');
});
```

As you can see, I've even 'imported' the controller, but it just can't find it.
That's it, no other files or changes to the project. Also tried clearing route cache and dump-autoload, but that did not change anything.

Comment: Capitalization matters - is there a file called `app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php`? Or is it perhaps `APIController.php`?

Comment: Why not just use 
Route::get('/base', 'ApiController@base')->name('base');

Comment: I believe, `'uses' => ....` add the default namespace . You can do this instead `[ApiController::class , 'base']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna ::class reference in the router, it should be done like this.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'as' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('base', [ApiController::class, 'base'])->name('base');
});
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case problew was, in `RouteServiceProvider`, in using routes **Namespace**

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

In Laravel 8 namespace was [commented out](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L29), i remove namespace from chain, because my web routes not fully moved to Laravel 8 syntax and i need this namespace.

```
 Route::prefix('api')
      ->middleware('api')   
      -̶>̶n̶a̶m̶e̶s̶p̶a̶c̶e̶(̶$̶t̶h̶i̶s̶-̶>̶n̶a̶m̶e̶s̶p̶a̶c̶e̶)̶
      ->group(base_path('routes/admin-api.php'));
```

Comment: This was the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'as' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('base', 'ApiController@base')->name('base');
});
```

No need to add the "use", since controllers are referenced from the App/Controllers namespace, as you can corroborate on the RouteServiceProvider.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your route is a combination of "old syntax" vs "new syntax"

What you are trying to achieve is:

```
Route::get('/base', [ApiController::class, 'base'])->name('base');
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove this line:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;
```

or add a `\` to the start:

```
use \App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Laravel 8 project), I needed a separate route for destroy, because deleting didn't use html form, so my `web.php` file is like:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\LocationController;
...
Route::resource('/locations', LocationController::class);
Route::get('/locations/destroy/{location}', [LocationController::class, 'destroy']);
```

But in that case if I put `use App\Http\Controllers\LocationController` the first line (`Route::resource...`) fails, if I remove it then the second line fails. So I removed `use` line and added `App\Http\Controllers` into the second line:

```
Route::resource('/locations', LocationController::class);
Route::get('/locations/destroy/{location}', [App\Http\Controllers\LocationController::class, 'destroy']);
```

So obviously Laravel doesn't automatically add `App\Http\Controllers` in the second form of `Route`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when in resource controller description me pasted one from fresh project:

```
Route::resources([
'my_url' => LisseyDoruHisobotController:class,
..., //other controllers
]);
```

as being a recommended signature in **Laravel 8** , but am currently busy on 7 or 6 version, where should be:

```
Route::resources([
'my_url' => 'path\to\LisseyDoruHisobotController',
..., //other controllers
]);
```

otherwize it will show doubled path

**Laravel Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ ] does not exist**